# Getting all senders Gmail API

Tags: email, gmail, gmail-api

Well, how can I get all senders in user's mail using Google APIs? I need a list of emails (and other ex. information). They are not in user's contacts cause he need to add them before. So there can I find this list?

I need to get a full list of people which write messages to user's email.

Comment: Welcome!  It is not clear to me what you are trying to do.  Can you be more verbose?

Comment: I need to get a full list of people which write messages to user's email. @JenniferGoncalves